# iOS NSDictionary description with members' type

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've a NSDictionary that contain non omogeneus stuff. I need to understand what types of memebers there are into.

With the [dict description] I understand the values into, but not the type. 
There is a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask each object for it's class (type) and then check if it's the type you want, using NSObject's -isKindOfClass: method. Note that if your object is, say, an NSMutableArray this would return true for [myMutableArray isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]

Example:

```
id object = [myDict objectForKey:aKey];
if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    // It's an NSString!
```

Source: [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass%3a)